# Can I define an axiomatic (Boolean algebra) system and prove theorems using Mathematica?

Tags: programming, evaluation, boolean-computation, proof

The general question is

> Can I define an axiomatic system and prove theorems using *Mathematica*?

The more concrete one is about Boolean algebra.

I consider this [axiomatic Boolean algebra system (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28structure%29#Definition).

> How can I
>
> 1. define the six (or twelve) axioms there in *Mathematica* and
> 2. then let *Mathematica* prove theorems in the *user-defined* axiomatic system, instead of the *built-in* system in *Mathematica*?
>
> (Theorems like: De Morgan's law ($\lnot(a \lor b) \equiv \lnot a \land \lnot b$) or the easier (maybe harder) ones such as $\lnot(\lnot a) \equiv a$ and $\lnot 0 \equiv 1$.

*You are not limited to Boolean algebra. You can show your skills in any fields you are good at.*

Comment: Wolfram is working on adding pure math to Mathematica, here is his blog on this [computational-knowledge-and-the-future-of-pure-mathematics/](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2014/08/computational-knowledge-and-the-future-of-pure-mathematics/) the idea is that one should be able to proof things and do more pure math using Mathematica. `Proofs can be generated or checked.` But this is for future versions.

Comment: @Nasser A really ambitious, impressive, interesting, and long blog article.

Comment: Theorema is a Mathematica package for proving theorems. Version 2 was presented at the Wolfram Conference in Fall 2014. https://www.risc.jku.at/research/theorema/software/?page=Download

Comment: TautologyQ[(\[Not] (a \[Or] b)) == (\[Not] a \[And] \[Not] b), {a, b}]

Comment: Also, you could do something like this: `Simplify[Equivalent[Not[Or[a, b]], And[Not[a], Not[b]]]]`.

Comment: @Jens Thanks. However, I want to prove theorems in user-defined axiomatic system, instead of the built-in system in *Mathematica*. Therefore, the first problem is how to define the axiomatic system in *Mathematica*.