# Finding transitive Boolean matrices

Tags: matrix, filtering, boolean-computation

I am fairly new here and with Mathematica too.
I have a question regarding Boolean matrices but before this I did a random search and got this
[Defining an arbitrary binary relation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86900/defining-an-arbitrary-binary-relation)

But I am unable to modify the code to get the desired results.

I am hoping to generate 3 × 3 Boolean matrices, there are 2^9 of them, and I need to know how many of those 2 ^ 9 Boolean matrices are transitive.

Can someone please put me in the right direction?

Thanks

Edit:

> Let A=(a_ij)∈M_n(B)  be a non-zero matrix. If for any i,j,k in I_n,
> where I_n={1,2,⋯,n}, when a_ij=a_jk=1 ，we have a_ik=1, then A is said
> to be transitive.

Futhermore

> A is transitive if and only if A^2≤A.

We can set a check on the validity by using the following

```
T[n_] := 
 n*(n - 1)^3 + 1/6*n*(n - 1)^4*(n - 2) + 
  1/6*n*(n - 1)*(n - 2)*(4*n - 1)
```

This works for only those boolean matrices which has 3 nonzero elements. For example in 3x3 there are 43 transitive matrices, for 4x4 there are 276 having only 3 nonzero elements.

**Edit 2.**

I got quick and very positive responses here, which I really appreciate. I have tried to adopt the answers but due to my lack of basic understanding of Mathematica, I am unable to get the desired results. here is what I am looking for

1. How to manange a code which can easily work for higher orders such is 3X3, 4X4, 5X5, 6X6?
2. I would like to incorporate all the matrices which satisfies the above two definitions more specificly A^2<=A
3. I would like to see the complete list of the transitive matrices that I can verify them manually If I had to.
4. It would be more helpful if the code includes verfication test as I have mentioned above.

I know I am asking for too much but this work if done manually is beyond my abilities.

Looking forward to your kind replies!

---

Comment: Do you have a test for transitivity? Use it on `ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 9];`.

Comment: A relevant post from [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228898/how-to-check-whether-a-relation-is-transitive-from-the-matrix-representation).

Comment: `trQ[k_?MatrixQ] := Unitize@MatrixPower[k, 2] == k` and `(res = Select[ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 9], 
    trQ]) // Length` gives me `123`. Am I wrong in using `MatrixPower` instead of `Dot`?

Comment: @Syed  some non zero base matrix  have square that is zero matrix. Further, some with 1 in base matrix can have zero in same position in square and still be counted as transitive. The condition is if two step path then there is edge in base matrix . If there is no two step path there may or may not be an edge in base matrix. Daniel Huber answer deals with this.

Comment: @Syed I have updated the question and included the transitivity test. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix m1 can be check for transitivity by:

- Dot multiply m1 with itself and set every element >1 to 1. This can be achieved by:

  m2= m1.m1 /.  x_ /; x > 1 -> 1
- Check if for each element of m2 that is 1, the corresponding element of m1 is also 1. This can be achieved by element wise multiplication of m1 and m2:

  m1 m2 == m2

Here is an example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
m1 = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
m2 = m1 . m1 /. x_ /; x > 1 -> 1
m1 m2 == m2

False
```

Or:

```
SeedRandom[5];
m1 = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {3, 3}]
m2 = m1 . m1 /. x_ /; x > 1 -> 1
m1 m2 == m2

True
```

If you now want to count which 3x3 boolean matrices are transitive, you may first create these 512 matrices. That can be done by noting that the flatten matrices are the numbers from 0..511 in binary notation. Then, having a list of digits, you can reshape them into a matrix and finally check the matrix. For the check we define a small function:

```
checkTrans[m1_] := Module[{m2},
  m2 = m1 . m1;
  m1 m2 == m2
  ]
ms = IntegerDigits[#, 2, 9] & /@ Range[0, 511];
ms = ArrayReshape[#, {3, 3}] & /@ ms;
Count[checkTrans /@ ms, True]

171
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But the problem is that I have to check it for all 512 matrices...here is all 512 matrices and how can I call them at once to check its transitivity.
Clear[boolmat]
boolmat[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Tuples[{0, 1}, {n, n}]
MatrixForm /@ boolmat[3]

Comment: Knowing how to check for transitivity, it is not difficult to count the 3x3 boolean transitive matrices. I added this to my answer.

Comment: How to see all those 63 of them, just to verify?

Comment: Use `Select[ms, checkTrans]` @Jonathan

Comment: @DanielHuber in your update answer you don’t Unitise the squared matrix (as you did in original). Any >1 two step paths in your component wise multiplication will not pass your test though from link they should, eg one of examples in link.

Comment: all 3X3 martices with only one nonzero element are transitive but from your list {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,1,0}} is missing...

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the test. Instead of m1 m2==m1, it should read m1 m2 == m2. I corrected this. Further, unitize is not necessary as the binary string from IntegerDigits consist only of 0 and 1.

Comment: How can we be sure that there are 171 transitive out of 512?

Comment: Do it in 2 different ways.

Comment: @Jonathan my answer misses cases where there is 1 in original matrix but 0 in the square. I am in error. I will delete my answer. I have already voted for Daniel Huber.

Comment: And those two different ways are? If you have time then can you please explain this in your answer along with its extension for higher order for example 4x4 and 5x5. Thanks

Comment: Please see the updated question...sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Comment: Does this includes all the transitive matrices which satisfies the condition A^2<=A?

Comment: I do not give recipes, I try to help people think.  Try to understand what I wrote,

Comment: You can write `checkTrans` slightly more efficiently `checkTrans[m1_] := With[{m2=m1.m1}, m1 m2 == m2]` - no need for the `Module`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to generate random boolean matrices, is like this:

```
(* Generate 1 random 3x3 matrix *)
RandomChoice[{True, False}, {3, 3}]

(* Generate 10 of them *)
RandomChoice[{True, False}, {10, 3, 3}]
```

Use `{0, 1}` instead of `{True, False}` if you want numbers instead of boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the updated question. Selecting only matrices with 3 non-zero entries and looking for transitivity.

I use the test of Daniel Huber (who I have voted for).

```
tst[m_] := With[{s = m . m}, s m == s]
num3[n_] := 
 Module[{sel = 
    ArrayReshape[#, {n, n}] & /@ (Permutations[
       ArrayPad[{1, 1, 1}, {0, n^2 - 3}]]), r},
  r = Select[sel, tst@# &];
  Length[r]]
```

Testing for 3x3 to 7x7 matrices:

```
  TableForm[Table[{Row[{j, "x", j}], num3[j]}, {j, 3, 7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Once again thanks for your efforts. I think you misunderstood me. I am looking for all the transitive matrices out of 512. The 3 nonzero elements matrices are just a validity test.

Comment: I have corrected my error

Comment: Daniel Huber answer works (IMHO) and passes your vailidiity check with 3 non-zero entries. My reply was too long for a comment.

Comment: How can I display the full list and the total number of the transitive matrices?

Comment: Does this includes all the matrices which satisfies the condition A^2<=A?

Comment: Not sure you mean by full list.  The table I present  was for your validity check for 3 non-zero case. The discussion on my original answer showed you how to display matrices in MatrixForm. I'll leave it up to you to experiment. I have a meeting right now.

Comment: Good luck with your meeting...

Comment: My point is how to display the list of all 3X3 or 4x4 transitive matrices...like in your orginal answer you suggested to use MatrixForm/@sel...but its not working in this case...

Comment: You should update or edit your question with the code you are using and then users may be able to help identify your error.  Good luck.

Comment: I followed your suggestion.

Comment: Whenever you have time then please have a look and this might solve the issues I am facing....