# Validity of the number of transitive matrices

Tags: matrix, boolean-computation

I am trying to generate all possible transitive boolean matrices of order nxn which satisfies the following definition of transitivity

> Let A=(a_ij)∈M_n(B) be a non-zero matrix. If for any i,j,k in I_n,
> where I_n={1,2,⋯,n}, when a_ij=a_jk=1 ，we have a_ik=1, then A is said
> to be transitive.
> and
> A is transitive if and only if A^2≤A.

The code I am adopting from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286138/finding-transitive-boolean-matrices) to extend it to nxn,

```
checkTrans[m1_] := Module[{m2}, m2 = m1 . m1; m1 m2 == m2]
```

To check the validity I am  using the following

```
 T1[n_] := n*(n - 1)^3 + 1/6*n*(n - 1)^4*(n - 2) + 
  1/6*n*(n - 1)*(n - 2)*(4*n - 1)
T2[n_] := 1/2*n*(n - 1)*(n^2 - n + 3)
T3[n_] := n*(2^n - 1)
```

T1 validity test works for only those transitive boolean matrices which has 3 nonzero elements. For example in 3x3 there are 43 transitive matrices, for 4x4 there are 276 having only 3 nonzero elements.

T2 test works for the number of n × n transitive Boolean matrices with two nonzero elements.

T3 denotes the number of transitive Boolean matrices with 1 non-0 columns in the Boolean matrices of nxn

```
     n = 3; (*martix order*)
    
    ms = IntegerDigits[#, 2, n^2] & /@ Range[0, 2^(n^2) - 1];
    ms = ArrayReshape[#, {n, n}] & /@ ms;
    
    validMatrices = 
      Select[ms, Count[Flatten[#], 1] == 3 && checkTrans[#] &];
    validity = Length[validMatrices] == T1[n];
    
    validMatrices2 = 
      Select[ms, Count[Flatten[#], 1] == 2 && checkTrans[#] &];
    validity2 = Length[validMatrices2] == T2[n];
    func[x_] := 
 Length[Union[SparseArray[x]["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]]]] == 1
    validMatrices3 = Select[ms, func];
    validity3 = Length[Select[validMatrices3, checkTrans]] == T3[n];
    
    {validity, validity2, validity3}

{True, True, True}
```

(validity3 fails. I am trying to make sure, that the number of all the possible transitive matrices generated by checkTrans are accurate.) @ubpdqn helped to solve this issue.

The remaining issues are

Is this the correct way to find the numbers of transitive Boolean matrices in nxn boolean matrices with 4 non-zero elements in each transitive Boolean matrix?

`Select[ms, Total[Flatten[#]] == 4 && checkTrans[#] &];`

Finally, this code takes ages for 5x5.

Please have a look!

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what T3 means. It may be that your selection criterion for validity3 is not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer relates to the second part regarding 4 non-zero entries in n xn matrix.

```
Select[ms, Total[Flatten[#]] == 4 && checkTrans[#] &];
```

does do this but falters as n increases (size 2^(n^2)).

A first approach would be to just deal with the matrices of interest. For example (this is some code I had written earlier):

```
tst[m_] := With[{s = m . m}, s m == s]
numz[n_, nz_] := 
 Module[{sel = 
    ArrayReshape[#, {n, n}] & /@ (Permutations[
       ArrayPad[ConstantArray[1, nz], {0, n^2 - nz}]]), r},
  r = Select[sel, tst];
  Length[r]]
```

So OP can check if expected results:

```
TableForm[
 Table[{Row[{j, "x", j}], numz[j, 4], Multinomial[j^2 - 4, 4]}, {j, 3,
    7}]]
```

[image]

The first column is matrix dimensions, the second column the number of transitive matrices, the last column the number of matrices with 4 non-zero entries.

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: Is this the correct way to find the square root? roots = MatrixPower[#, 1/2] & /@ r;

Answer (score 2):

This is a *long comment* seeking to clarify the meaning of T3.

A criterion to select T3 (an interpretation):

```
 func[x_] := 
 Length[Union[SparseArray[x]["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 2]]]]== 1
```

Selecting T3 matrices:

```
  a = Select[ms, func]
```

Showing these matrices for OP to see if this is what T3 means:

```
Grid[Partition[MatrixForm /@ a, 3]
```

[image: graphic of matrices]

If these are the intended T3 matrices then:

`Length[Select[a, checkTrans]] == T3[3]` yields `True`.

Note: all 21 of T3 matrices are transitive.

Comment: This suggests you code to select T3 is wrong and as expressed before Daniel Huber answer  remains correct.

Comment: You are copying verbatim what you write. That is not a clarification. It is a verbatim restatement. Your first comment suggest the desired matrices to be tested were selected by func (my function). Applying checkTrans to this is correct with respect to your T3. This suggests your code is wrong. Finally, the reason  larger cases will be problematic is size of space becomes intractable. I am not sure what your ultimate aim is but it is likely to need mathematical insights with or without clever algorithms to count cases. Good luck :)

Comment: I just want to express it is ok to be wrong. My code to the original question was wrong. I deleted it to not mislead and I learned something. Where I think your error is occurs in validityMatrices3:  where you try to select the T3 cases. The more you play with Mathematica you will gain insights into it and your problem.

Comment: You are right! you have guessed it correctly. This is what T3 means

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SatisfiabilityCount` for this task, the counts are $\{2, 13, 171, 3994, 154303, 9415189,878222530\}$, appearing to follow [A006905](https://oeis.org/A006905)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
booleanMatmul[mat1_, mat2_] := 
  Array[Inner[And, mat1[[#1, ;;]], mat2[[;; , #2]], Or] &, {Length[
     mat1], Length[mat2]}];
booleanEquals[mat1_, mat2_] := 
  And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Xnor, {mat1, mat2}, 2];
booleanGreaterEqual[mat1_, mat2_] := 
  And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Or[#1, Not[#2]] &, {mat1, mat2}, 2];

countWeaklyTransitive[d_] := (
   mat = Array[x, {d, d}];
   mat2 = booleanMatmul[mat, mat];
   SatisfiabilityCount[booleanGreaterEqual[mat2, mat], Flatten[mat]]
   );
countWeaklyTransitive /@ Range[5]
```

Comment: Thats perfect now. I get the same numbers with the code suggested in another answer.

Comment: Now How can we find the number of the square matrices of the these TBMs?

Comment: Why weakly transitive?

Comment: @Jonathan I see people [use](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228898/how-to-check-whether-a-relation-is-transitive-from-the-matrix-representation) "transitive" to mean if-and-only-if, in which case there are 11 such 2x2 matrices. Your definition only has the "if" part, so we get 13 such 2x2 matrices. Hence, I'm calling your definition "weakly transitive" to differentiate

Comment: My sincere apologies for my lose language. The actual defintion is "if and only if".

Comment: @Jonathan in that case, transitive is the same as my definition of "idempotent". (idempotent under "boolean matrix multiplication"). `genIdempotentSquare` in the other [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286752/217) gives the list of matrices such that their square is "transitive/idempotent"

Comment: Thanks! Can you please find the square root of all the TBMs here in your answer? It would be helpful if you can list the matrices its square root. Any order is ok for me.

Comment: That's what `genIdempotentSquare` does in that [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286550/square-root-of-a-boolen-matrix/286752), it lists all squares roots of all idempotent matrices ($A^2=A$), meanwhile `genWeaklyTransitiveSquare` lists all square roots of all weakly transitive matrices ($A^2\le A$)