# Square Root of a Boolean Matrix

Tags: boolean-computation

I am trying to find the square roots of transitive Boolean matrices.

> Let $B$ be a transitive Boolean matrix, If $A^2= B$, then $A$ is the square root of $B$.

Here is my try

```
checkTrans[m1_] := Module[{m2}, m2 = m1 . m1; m1 m2 == m2]
n = 3; (*martix order*)
ms = IntegerDigits[#, 2, n^2] & /@ Range[0, 2^(n^2) - 1];
ms = ArrayReshape[#, {n, n}] & /@ ms;

squareRoots = 
  Flatten[Function[{m}, 
     Select[MatrixPower[#, 1/2] & /@ 
       ms, # \[Element] Reals && 
        AllTrue[Flatten[#], # == 0 || # == 1 &] && checkTrans[m] &]] /@
     ms, 1];

Length[squareRoots]
Print["Matrices with Existing Square Roots (Boolean):"];
MatrixForm /@ squareRoots
```

For 2x2, I am getting 8 martices. How to make sure that I am getting all the possible square roots matrices of each matrix?
As expected, for 3x3 its very slow, any suggestions?

> It's worth noting that not every Boolean matrix has a square root.
> Some Boolean matrices may not have a square root, while others may
> have multiple square roots.

Comment: For efficiency, replace both `validMatrices = Select[ms, MatrixPower[#, 1/2] \[Element] Reals &]; squareRoots = MatrixPower[#, 1/2] & /@ validMatrices;` with just `squareRoots = Select[MatrixPower[#, 1/2] & /@ ms, # \[Element] Reals &];`

Comment: @BobHanlon the output should be a Boolean matrix...

Answer (score 1):

You could turn this into [SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) problem and use `SatisfiabilityInstances`.

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-boolean-matrices.nb)

### Generate all $d\times d$ boolean matrices such that their square is weakly transitive

Weakly transitive means $A\ge A^2$

Number of such matrices grows as $\{2, 16, 432, 32242, 739848\}$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ClearAll["Global`*"];
booleanMatmul[mat1_, mat2_] := 
  Array[Inner[And, mat1[[#1, ;;]], mat2[[;; , #2]], Or] &, {Length[
     mat1], Length[mat2]}];
booleanEquals[mat1_, mat2_] := 
  And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Xnor, {mat1, mat2}, 2];
booleanGreaterEqual[mat1_, mat2_] := 
  And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Or[#1, Not[#2]] &, {mat1, mat2}, 2];

genWeaklyTransitiveSquare[d_] := Block[{x},
   mat = Array[x, {d, d}];
   vars = Flatten[mat];
   
   mat2 = booleanMatmul[mat, mat];
   mat4 = booleanMatmul[mat2, mat2];
   sat = booleanGreaterEqual[mat2, mat4];
   
   numSolutions = SatisfiabilityCount[sat, vars];
   booleSolutions = SatisfiabilityInstances[sat, vars, numSolutions];
   On[Assert]; Assert[Length@booleSolutions == numSolutions];
   (*Convert solutions to matrix form*)
   matrixSolutions = mat /. Thread[vars -> Boole@#] & /@ booleSolutions
   ];
MatrixForm /@ genWeaklyTransitiveSquare[3]
```

### Generate all $d\times d$ boolean matrices such that their square is idempotent

Counts grow as ${2,16,420,31114,7192088}$

```
genIdempotentSquare[d_] := (
   mat = Array[x, {d, d}];
   vars = Flatten[mat];
   
   (*construct mat^2 using And/Or instead of*/+*)
   mat2 = Array[
     Inner[And, mat[[#1, ;;]], mat[[;; , #2]], Or] &, {d, d}];
   mat4 = 
    Array[Inner[And, mat2[[#1, ;;]], mat2[[;; , #2]], Or] &, {d, d}];
   sat = And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Xnor, {mat2, mat4}, 2];
   numSolutions = SatisfiabilityCount[sat, vars];
   booleSolutions = SatisfiabilityInstances[sat, vars, numSolutions];
   On[Assert]; Assert[Length@booleSolutions == numSolutions];
   
   (*Convert solutions to matrix form*)
   matrixSolutions = mat /. Thread[vars -> Boole@#] & /@ booleSolutions
   );
MatrixForm /@ genIdempotentSquare[3]
```

### List all boolean idempotent matrices of size $d\times d$

Counts grow as $1, 2, 11, 123, 2360$, [A121337](https://oeis.org/A121337)

```
d = 3;
mat = Array[x, {d, d}];
vars = Flatten[mat];

(*construct mat^2 using And/Or instead of*/+*)
mat2 = Array[
   Inner[And, mat[[#1, ;;]], mat[[;; , #2]], Or] &, {d, d}];
sat = And @@ Flatten@MapThread[Xnor, {mat, mat2}, 2];

numSolutions = SatisfiabilityCount[sat, vars];
booleSolutions = SatisfiabilityInstances[sat, vars, numSolutions];
On[Assert]; Assert[Length@booleSolutions == numSolutions];

(*Convert solutions to matrix form*)
matrixSolutions = mat /. Thread[vars -> Boole@#] & /@ booleSolutions;
Print["Solutions idempotent: ", 
  AllTrue[matrixSolutions, Boole@Positive[# . #] == # &]];
MatrixForm /@ matrixSolutions
```

### List all square roots of given boolean matrix

For `IdentityMatrix[d]` target, counts grow as [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
target = IdentityMatrix[4];

Clear[x];
d = Length[target];
mat = Array[x, {d, d}];
vars = Flatten[mat];

(*construct mat^2 using And/Or instead of*/+*)
mat2 = Array[Inner[And, mat[[#1, ;;]], mat[[;; , #2]], Or] &, {d, d}];

(* construct SAT problem *)
posClauses = Extract[mat2, Position[target, 1]];
negClauses = Not /@ Extract[mat2, Position[target, 0]];
sat = (And @@ posClauses)~And~(And @@ negClauses);

(* solve SAT problem *)
numSolutions = SatisfiabilityCount[sat, vars];
booleSolutions = SatisfiabilityInstances[sat, vars, numSolutions];
On[Assert]; Assert[Length@booleSolutions == numSolutions];

(* Convert solutions to matrix form *)
matrixSolutions = mat /. Thread[vars -> Boole@#] & /@ booleSolutions;
MatrixForm /@ matrixSolutions
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input...I did a quick check for 2x2 and it produces only two square matrices. Is your code trying to find square root of all the 4x4 Boolean matrices or the transitive Boolean matrices? or just for identity matrices?

Comment: It finds all square roots of a given boolean matrix, stored in variable `target`

Comment: OK! But I am looking for all the square roots of all the boolean of 2x2 or 3x3 or 4x4...

Comment: @Jonathan hm, that sounds like all matrices. Any boolean matrix mat is a square root of matrix mat.mat

Comment: `n = 2; (*matrix order*)
ms = IntegerDigits[#, 2, n^2] & /@ Range[0, 2^(n^2) - 1];
ms = ArrayReshape[#, {n, n}] & /@ ms;

booleanSquareRoots = 
  Select[ms, 
   MatrixPower[#, 2] == # && 
     AllTrue[Flatten[#], # == 0 || # == 1 &] &];

Length[booleanSquareRoots]
Print["Boolean Square Root Matrices:"];
MatrixForm /@ booleanSquareRoots` Here is the code for 2x2 but I am not sure about the output number

Comment: Are you perhaps asking for a list of all boolean [idempotent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) of given size?

Comment: I am asking for the sqaure root of all 2x2 Boolean matrices which are 2^4=16 in total...

Comment: @Jonathan so you have 16 matrices, but there's only 16 boolean matrices of that size. Every boolean matrix is a square root of some boolean matrix, so it sounds like you are asking how to list all boolean matrices

Comment: Thats right! There are total number of 16 BMs of 2x2 and my code generates square root of 8.

Comment: @Jonathan I think you have a bug in your `checkTrans` function, you are using pointwise mutliplication `m1 m2`  instead of matrix multiplication `m1.m2`, so you are not actually checking if matrix is transitive. I've edited my answer to list all transitive boolean matrices of a given size

Comment: BTW, you can chain the two functions to list all square roots of all transitive matrices, in this [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-boolean-matrices.nb) I can see there are 420 such matrices of size $3\times 3$

Comment: Well, as for as transitive BMs are concern, I am not just looking for idempotent but all transitive satisfiying this condition $A^2<=A$.

Comment: @Jonathan ok, I've updated the answer, `genIdempotentSquare[3]` generates all 3x3 matrices that satisfy your constraint. The number of such matrices grows quite fast with $d$, I see counts $\{2, 16, 420, 31114, 7192088\}$

Comment: I think, there is a missunderstanding. here is what I want... I want to generate all the transitive matrices for 2x2 and higher order which satisfies this condition (A is transitive if and only if $A2<=A$). 2. Then I want to find the square root of all those transitive matrices. 3. I want to find the square root of all the Boolean matrices of order 2x2 or higher...
.

Comment: @Jonathan this is what `genIdempotentSquare[d]` does. It generates all $d\times d$ boolean matrices $A$ such that boolean matrix $A^2$ is transitive. For $d=2$ it's all matrices, but for $d=3$, it's $420$ which is less than $512$, the total number of matrices

Comment: For 2x2 we already know that there only 13 TBMs. For details please check this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286314/validity-of-the-number-of-transitive-matrices

Comment: The last one "square roots of BM" is just generating the number of BM, i.e, 2x2 is 16, 3x3 is 512, 4x4 is 65536...